# Find available RTMP channels on a media server (e.g. Adobe)

Tags: rtmp, flash-media-server

I am planning a software application where the user will be able to select a given media channel from a list of RTMP streams available on one or more media servers on the internet. The list should ideally be dynamically created through some kind of service that knows about the available and active channels.

*My question is:* Would this be possible through some kind of protocol between the service and the media server. I understand that RTMP by itself doesn't allow this. A therefore assume that some outbound mechanism will be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No...

...there is no native application discovery in RTMP.  If you'd like this kind of functionality you'll need to program some sort of discovery service for which ever streaming server you are running.